# Empty array trying to get all the review of product with the product id in the review table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I'm trying to get the review of a product by the product Id in the review table but i do get an empty array or nothing 
this are my code.

```
public function index(Product $product)
{
    return $product->reviews;

}

public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\Product');
}

public function reviews(){
   return $this->hasMany(Review::class);
}
```

[migration code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLh9o.png)

[ReviewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcHZS.png)

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('reviews', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('customer');
        $table->integer('star');
        $table->text('review');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id')->index();
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: try first if the $product have value. using `dd($product);`

Comment: how you are calling `index` function  ?

Comment: share your table structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
$product->with('reviews');
```

Comment: I think he want only `reviews`

Comment: Yes the reviews of a product

Comment: This will fetch the all product with all corresponding reviews. you can transform data through transformer.

or if you want only review table data you can do $review::all();

Comment: this the error i get using the code above ---  "Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string"